# How to load a string from the resource of a different process?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I need to load a string which is placed in the resource dll of a different process, provided that the process will be running at the time of call.

I tried following code -

```
    HMODULE hRes = ::LoadLibrary(_T("SomeResource.dll"));

    TCHAR buffer[50];
    ::LoadString(hRes, IDS_SOME_ID, buffer, 50);
```

This code is working fine while running in debug mode.
But in release mode LoadLibrary returns zero. Why?

Am I missing something? Please help me.

I am using VC7.1 compiler.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` say? Maybe SomeResource.dll is not compiled/deployed in the Release directory.

Comment: is SomeResource.dll is in the Release directory (or the same directory from which you are running your release exe)?

Comment: yes, found the problem. SomeResource.dll is in a different dir than where the release exe is... used FullPath for the dll and ... it works.

Thanks every body for quick help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a problem of *finding* `"SomeResource.dll"`. When you run from the debugger, the executable is started from the project's path. If the DLL can be found from there. it's fine. When you run from outside the IDE, the executable is started from a different folder. It migh be that the DLL cannot be found from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretended on answer, but could please add following code to diagnose problem:

```
if( hRes == 0 ){
LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
DWORD dw = GetLastError();

FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
    NULL,
    dw,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0, NULL );


MessageBox(NULL, (LPTSTR)lpMsgBuf, "Error", MB_OK);

LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
}
```

Comment: Why make `lpMsgBuf` a `LPVOID` just to cast it to `LPTSTR` everywhere you use it? Why not make it `LPTSTR` right from the start?

Comment: @sbi - I have provided this code just for diagnostic. Could you try and tell us whats wrong with DLL, to let us answer you question